# What exactly happens when git creates a branch does it copy files from main folder?

Tags: git

So I decided to learn git to host a little project for school using github pages, this is my first day with git and I think I understand a bit how it works, however I'm curious to know what happens when I create a branch, does git copy files from main folder to another folder ? How does it revert changes when I do `checkout master` (on sublime text I immediately see changes) ? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What happens when I create a branch?

Nothing on the working tree (the files on your disk), git creates a new ref pointing to the current commit. That's why creating branches is so fast.

> How does it revert changes when I do checkout master?

It updates the working tree to match the master branch, working out just what needs to change to achieve that.

I suggest you read this to properly grok what's going on: http://ftp.newartisans.com/pub/git.from.bottom.up.pdf